# Bluemix VMs on eu-gb: OS_TENANT_ID missing from CLI file

Tags: virtual-machine, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

VMs is up on eu-gb region which is great.

However Horizon does not appear to be installed on there, which is fine, as I use the CLI most of the time. However the CLI file that I download from the Bluemix console is not correct.

It is missing the OS_TENANT_ID property. I cannot connect to my OpenStack tenant without this. Where can I get tenant ID from?

Answer (score 0):

according to Bluemix VM documentation

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_setup_cli

you should login into your region&org and download the rc file one you are going to create the first VM.
The rc file download following these steps will contain all the information you need to access and manage your VM on Bluemix using openstack client.

In the case of you already downloaded your rc file following these steps I suggest you to try again generating a new one to check the new one contains all the information you need (consider that this environment is still beta and this kind of issues could be expected)